# Image Width Height Via AngularJS (ng-file-upload)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need to validate the image width - height on the basis of 1:3 ratio. I am using ng-file-upload to upload the image. The validation needs to be done before sending it to server.

I am clueless about how to get the image width/height from the selected image. Can somebody help me out ?

I am following the tutorial from this site : 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/03/building-a-filereader-service-for-angularjs-the-service.aspx

Comment: Could you submit a feature request in the issues of the github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a feature request for the plugin.
As a workaround you can do this:

```
<div ngf-select ngf-model="image" ngf-validate-fn-async="validateRatio(image)" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" >

$scope.validateRatio = function(image) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  Upload.imageDimensions(image).then(function(d) {
    if (d.width / d.height === expectedRatio) {
      defer.resolve()
    } else {
      defer.reject();
    }
  }, function() {defer.reject();});
  return defer.promise;
}
```

or

```
<div ngf-select ngf-model="image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-min-height="0" accept="image/*" >
<div ng-show="image.width && (image.width / image.height !== expectedRatio)">Invalid ratio?
```

**EDIT**
Feature is added
You can have

```
<div ngf-select ngf-model="image" ngf-ratio="1x3" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" >
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have uploaded the file, are you assigning the DOM element with an ID? If so, plain JS could work such as:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 

var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks Oam Psy for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var image = angular.element('<CLASS_NAME or ID_NAME>');
    $scope.width = image.width();
    $scope.height = image.height();
```

Hope this helps You!.